# Sql code returns unexpected results. How to correct it

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm using Firebird 3. There are 'sellers' master table for my contragent sellers, detailed 'Doc' table for goods income documents and subdetail table 'paym' for payments.

**Seller**: Seller_id, seller
**Docs**: doc_id, doc_summa, part_id
**Paym**: paid_id, doc_id, paid

**Seller:**

| seller_id | seller |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | Firm1 |
| 45 | Firm2 |

**Docs:**

| doc_id | doc_summa | seller_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 346 | 1000 | 8 |
| 347 | 600 | 45 |
| 348 | 800 | 45 |

**Paym:**

| paym_id | doc_id | paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 346 | 100 |
| 2 | 346 | 100 |
| 3 | 347 | 200 |
| 4 | 348 | 100 |
| 5 | 348 | 50 |

My aim is to get my residual debts(income-payment) like this:

| seller_id | summa | paid | debt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1000 | 200 | 800 |
| 45 | 1400 | 350 | 1050 |

but get this multiplied, wrong summas:

| seller_id | summa | paid | debt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 2000 | 200 | 800 |
| 45 | 2200 | 350 | 1850 |

```
SELECT
 s.seller_id, 
 sum(d.doc_summa) as summa,
 sum(p.paid) as paid,
 sum(d.doc_summa)-sum(p.paid) as debt

FROM seller s Left Join Docs d  on s.seller_id=d.seller_id
             Left Join  paym p  on p.doc_id= d.doc_id

GROUP BY s.seller_id
```

What is wrong in my SQL code?

Comment: @Dai Real sql will be difficult to perception because of non-english names of tables and fields.  Theafore I change there names.   I correect selelr_id---->seller_id

Comment: Create a new database with only this data and make sure the result is still incorrect

Comment: @mousetail  I create a new db.  There is onedrive link of screen. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AukGXPQiR2IpiPFjh_ad5pN8d3Q_aw?e=92yKsL

Comment: This is because there are two entries in paym for doc_id 346, so there are two rows, and when summed together, that results in 2000, same for doc_id 348, resulting in that 800 being counted twice.

Comment: Fiddle to reproduce: https://dbfiddle.uk/I5vDJatP

Comment: @Dai The query does produce the result the OP is showing, and it is "correct" (for the given query).

Comment: When you remove the `sum` functions, and remove the GROUP BY, you should be able to tell where the _wrong summas_ are coming from.   (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/8A4T3w__ )   (600+800+800 = 2200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that because there are multiple payments for doc_ids 346 and 348, you will have two rows with a doc_summa of 1000 and 800 respectively, when you then sum them, the total becomes 2000 for seller_id 8 and 2200 for seller_id 45.

To solve this, you need to consolidate (sum) the payments *before* joining with docs. For example like the following:

```sql
with consolidated_paym as (
  select 
    doc_id, 
    sum(paid) as total_paid
  from paym
  group by doc_id
)
select
  s.seller_id,
  sum(d.doc_summa) as summa,
  sum(p.total_paid) as paid,
  sum(d.doc_summa - p.total_paid) as debt
from seller s
left join docs d
  on d.seller_id = s.seller_id
left join consolidated_paym as p
  on p.doc_id = d.doc_id
group by s.seller_id
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/6_vyCu0w

Comment: Mark Rotteveel thank you very much. It works correctly.